# "How can I display a 95% CI for continuous variables in overall columns using gtsummary::add_ci()?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I've noticed that add_ci() functions differently for various types of variables. Specifically, it doesn't work for continuous variables in overall columns. However, 95% confidence intervals (CIs) are displayed for categorical variables in overall columns and for both continuous and categorical variables in stratified columns. Is this the intended behavior for add_ci()?

```
  mydata %>%
    tbl_summary(
      by = Sex,
      type = list(
        all_continuous() ~ "continuous"
      ),
      statistic = list(
        all_continuous() ~ c("{mean} ({sd})")
      )
    ) %>%
    add_overall() %>%
    add_ci()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFjBm.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that wll be addressed in the next release.

In the meantime, this will get you the table you need.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

# no by variable
tbl1 <-
  mtcars |> 
  tbl_summary(include = c(mpg, am), statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})") |> 
  modify_header(stat_0 = "**Overall** N = {N}") |> 
  add_ci()

# with by variable
tbl2 <-
  mtcars |> 
  tbl_summary(by = vs, include = c(mpg, am), statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})") |> 
  add_ci() 

# merge tables together
tbl_merge(list(tbl1, tbl2), tab_spanner = FALSE) |> 
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **Overall** N = 32 | **95% CI** | **0**, N = 18 | **95% CI** | **1**, N = 14 | **95% CI** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mpg | 20.1 (6.0) | 18, 22 | 16.6 (3.9) | 15, 19 | 24.6 (5.4) | 21, 28 |
| am | 13 (41%) | 24%, 59% | 6 (33%) | 14%, 59% | 7 (50%) | 27%, 73% |

<sup>Created on 2023-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your swift response! It is much helpful.